# Not able to install or update cocoa pods after updating xcode 6

Tags: iphone, cocoapods

I have updated xcode 6. after that i am not able to update pod using terminal. when i am trying to do pod update with "pod update", terminal is stuck & not updating it. please check below image. i am trying to update pods.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it by doing below steps..

1. Uninstall cocoapods
       $ sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
2. Uninstall xcodeproj
       $ sudo gem uninstall xcodeproj
3. Install xcodeproj
       $ sudo gem install xcodeproj
4. Install cocoapods
       $ sudo gem install cocoapods

Run pod --version to verify that it worked or not.

Now its cocoa pods updating successfully.

Answer (score 0):

While your going to update your pods you just focus on the below terminal commands.These commands is more than enough for update our pods.

For me it's working fine.!

Hope it may help you.

```
$sudo gem update —system
$sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
$sudo gem install cocoapods
$pod setup
$cd <project path>
$pod init
add files(frameworks)($pod outdated- if already pod exists)
$pod install
$pod update(if you need)
```